# Deploying to Unix server instead of Windows server causes "XML Parsing Error: no element found"

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, weblogic12c

I use primefaces v 5.1. My jsf page throws 'XML Parsing Error: no element found' error. The interesting part is my jsf page works fine in weblogic 12c installed in windows server. But when I deploy the web application in weblogic installed in unix server it throws me this error. There are not other errors shown in the server logs. Can someone help on this ?

my jsf page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


            <h:head>
                <title><h:outputText value="#{label.disclaimerHeading}" /></title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
                    href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/css/not.css" />
                <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/not.js"></script>
            </h:head>

            <h:body>
                <f:view>
                    <h:form id="xyzAbcForm">

                        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="pageHeading">
                            <h:outputText value="#{label.xyzAbcHeading}" />
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        <br />

                        <p:messages autoUpdate="true" />

                        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="information">
                            <h:outputText value="#{businessText.xyzAbcInfo}" />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        <br />

                        <h:outputText value="#{businessText.madatoryFieldsInfo}"
                            style="font-style:italic" />
                        <br />
                        <br />


                        <p:panelGrid columns="6" cellspacing="15px"
                            styleClass="table_background">

                            <p:outputLabel value="#{label.nca}" for="nca" styleClass="label" />
                            <p:inputText id="nca" required="true"
                                value="#{xyzAbcBean.qwe}" disabled="true" />

                            <p:outputLabel value="#{label.memberState}" for="memberState"
                                styleClass="label" />
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="memberState"
                                value="#{xyzAbcBean.xyzAbc.memberState}" required="true">
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Please select" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{xyzAbcBean.xyzAbc.memberStates}"
                                    var="country" itemValue="#{country.isoCountryCode}"
                                    itemLabel="#{country.countryName}" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>

                            <p:outputLabel value="#{label.date}" for="date" styleClass="label" />
                            <p:calendar id="date"
                                value="#{xyzAbcBean.xyzAbc.dateOfPermission}"
                                pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" styleClass="field" required="true"
                                navigator="true" disabled="true" />

                        </p:panelGrid>

                        <br />

                        <p:panelGrid columns="3" cellspacing="15px"
                            styleClass="table_background">


                            <p:outputLabel value="#{label.article}" for="article"
                                styleClass="label" />
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="article"
                                value="#{xyzAbcBean.xyzAbc.article}" required="true">
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Please select" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{xyzAbcBean.xyzAbc.articles}"
                                    var="article" itemValue="#{article.article}"
                                    itemLabel="#{article.articleDescription}" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                            <p:message for="article" styleClass="errorMessage" />


                            <p:outputLabel value="#{label.comments}" for="comments"
                                styleClass="label" />
                            <h:panelGroup>
                                <p:inputTextarea id="comments" cols="100" rows="10"
                                    value="#{xyzAbcBean.xyzAbc.comments}" maxlength="1000"
                                    counter="commentsCounter" required="true"
                                    counterTemplate="#{label.remaining}" styleClass="field"
                                    style="#{ not component.valid ? 'background-color:#FFCCCC' : ''}" />
                                <br />
                                <h:outputText id="commentsCounter" styleClass="remaining" />
                            </h:panelGroup>

                            <p:message for="comments" styleClass="errorMessage" />


                        </p:panelGrid>
                        <br />

                        <p:commandButton id="submitButton" value="#{button.submit}"
                            action="#{xyzAbcBean.submitAction}" ajax="false" />

                        <p:spacer width="5px" />

                        <p:commandButton id="reset" type="reset" value="#{button.reset}"
                            ajax="false" />

                    </h:form>
                </f:view>
            </h:body>
            </html>
```

my maven dependencies

```
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>abc.xyz.not</groupId>
                        <artifactId>not_business</artifactId>
                        <version>${not.project.version}</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <!-- EBA common dependencies -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>abc.xyz.common</groupId>
                        <artifactId>abc_common</artifactId>
                        <version>${abc.project.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>abc.xyz.common.business</groupId>
                        <artifactId>abc_common_business</artifactId>
                        <version>${abc.project.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>abc.xyz.common.presentation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>abc_common_presentation</artifactId>
                        <version>${abc.project.version}</version>
                    </dependency>


                    <!-- CAS -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jasig.cas.client</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cas-client-core</artifactId>
                        <version>3.3.3</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <!-- Spring -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4.1.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>


                    <!-- Spring Security -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
                    </dependency>


                    <!-- Primefaces -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
                        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cupertino</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.10</version>
                    </dependency>


                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.0</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                        <version>7.0</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
                        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                        <version>3.3.2</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.3</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <!-- From oracle client file directory -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                        <version>12.1.0.1.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
```

Request Headers

```
                        https://eb2dv-web01.abcuk.local:7002/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Feb2dv-web01.abcuk.local%3A7002%2Fnot%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check%3Bjsessionid%3D0z5LJvXWwT2fD6HTFMz4MZbNXWb2ZQyKXByLq8MC1pyLmKhy8ZFG%21-1130444011

            POST /cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Feb2dv-web01.abcuk.local%3A7002%2Fnot%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check%3Bjsessionid%3D0z5LJvXWwT2fD6HTFMz4MZbNXWb2ZQyKXByLq8MC1pyLmKhy8ZFG%21-1130444011 HTTP/1.1
            Host: eb2dv-web01.abcuk.local:7002
            User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0
            Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
            Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
            Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
            Referer: https://eb2dv-web01.abcuk.local:7002/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Feb2dv-web01.abcuk.local%3A7002%2Fnot%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check%3Bjsessionid%3D0z5LJvXWwT2fD6HTFMz4MZbNXWb2ZQyKXByLq8MC1pyLmKhy8ZFG%21-1130444011
            Cookie: JSESSIONID=0z5LJvXWwT2fD6HTFMz4MZbNXWb2ZQyKXByLq8MC1pyLmKhy8ZFG!-1130444011
            Connection: keep-alive
            Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            Content-Length: 150
            username=gopi&password=Password01&otp=12345678&lt=LT-46-VH3qKnViSYgU5sqCfENhSYoMshjyH2-cas01.abc.xyz.qw&execution=e1s1&_eventId=submit&submit=LOGIN
            HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
            Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
            Connection: close
            Date: Fri, 09 Jan 2015 13:30:51 GMT
            Pragma: no-cache
            Transfer-Encoding: chunked
            Location: https://eb2dv-web01.abcuk.local:7002/not/j_spring_cas_security_check;jsessionid=0z5LJvXWwT2fD6HTFMz4MZbNXWb2ZQyKXByLq8MC1pyLmKhy8ZFG!-1130444011?ticket=ST-80-Dr26pM01uqwsEyAkPgoN-cas01.abc.xyz.qw
            Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
            Set-Cookie: CASPRIVACY=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 01:00:00 GMT; path=/cas/
            Set-Cookie: CASTGC=TGT-26-sPJj0VAP1hchC27Nirt4rKPqadUDtiNWMc99gJBLI50NJLAAQP-cas01.abc.xyz.qw; path=/cas/; secure
            X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2
            ----------------------------------------------------------
            https://eb2dv-web01.abcuk.local:7002/not/j_spring_cas_security_check;jsessionid=0z5LJvXWwT2fD6HTFMz4MZbNXWb2ZQyKXByLq8MC1pyLmKhy8ZFG!-1130444011?ticket=ST-80-Dr26pM01uqwsEyAkPgoN-cas01.abc.xyz.qw

            GET /not/j_spring_cas_security_check;jsessionid=0z5LJvXWwT2fD6HTFMz4MZbNXWb2ZQyKXByLq8MC1pyLmKhy8ZFG!-1130444011?ticket=ST-80-Dr26pM01uqwsEyAkPgoN-cas01.abc.xyz.qw HTTP/1.1
            Host: eb2dv-web01.abcuk.local:7002
            User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0
            Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
            Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
            Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
            Referer: https://eb2dv-web01.abcuk.local:7002/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Feb2dv-web01.abcuk.local%3A7002%2Fnot%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check%3Bjsessionid%3D0z5LJvXWwT2fD6HTFMz4MZbNXWb2ZQyKXByLq8MC1pyLmKhy8ZFG%21-1130444011
            Cookie: JSESSIONID=0z5LJvXWwT2fD6HTFMz4MZbNXWb2ZQyKXByLq8MC1pyLmKhy8ZFG!-1130444011
            Connection: keep-alive

            HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
            Connection: close
            Date: Fri, 09 Jan 2015 13:30:51 GMT
            Transfer-Encoding: chunked
            Location: https://eb2dv-web01.abcuk.local:7002/not/faces/homeHost.xhtml
            X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2
            ----------------------------------------------------------
            https://eb2dv-web01.abcuk.local:7002/not/faces/homeHost.xhtml

            GET /not/faces/homeHost.xhtml HTTP/1.1
            Host: eb2dv-web01.abcuk.local:7002
            User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0
            Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
            Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
            Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
            Referer: https://eb2dv-web01.abcuk.local:7002/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Feb2dv-web01.abcuk.local%3A7002%2Fnot%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check%3Bjsessionid%3D0z5LJvXWwT2fD6HTFMz4MZbNXWb2ZQyKXByLq8MC1pyLmKhy8ZFG%21-1130444011
            Cookie: JSESSIONID=0z5LJvXWwT2fD6HTFMz4MZbNXWb2ZQyKXByLq8MC1pyLmKhy8ZFG!-1130444011
            Connection: keep-alive

            HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
            Date: Fri, 09 Jan 2015 13:30:52 GMT
            Content-Length: 0
            ----------------------------------------------------------
            https://eb2dv-web01.abcuk.local:7002/favicon.ico

            GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
            Host: eb2dv-web01.abcuk.local:7002
            User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0
            Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
            Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
            Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
            Cookie: JSESSIONID=0z5LJvXWwT2fD6HTFMz4MZbNXWb2ZQyKXByLq8MC1pyLmKhy8ZFG!-1130444011
            Connection: keep-alive

            HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
            Date: Fri, 09 Jan 2015 13:30:52 GMT
            Content-Length: 1164
            Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
            X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2
            ----------------------------------------------------------
            https://eb2dv-web01.abcuk.local:7002/favicon.ico

            GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
            Host: eb2dv-web01.abcuk.local:7002
            User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0
            Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
            Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
            Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
            Cookie: JSESSIONID=0z5LJvXWwT2fD6HTFMz4MZbNXWb2ZQyKXByLq8MC1pyLmKhy8ZFG!-1130444011
            Connection: keep-alive

            HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
            Date: Fri, 09 Jan 2015 13:30:52 GMT
            Content-Length: 1164
            Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
            X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2
            ----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: *"not other errors shown in the server logs"*, are you with "other" really implying that the mentioned error is shown in the server log? This is namely a typical client side error, not a server side one. If it's indeed really server side, then there's likely means of classpath pollution as to JAXP/SAX libraries. You might want to list the libraries involved in the deployment so that the culprit can be picked out.

Comment: Hi balusc, I have added the list of my maven dependencies. Do I need to add anything else to the question ? I couldnt see even the mentioned error in my server logs or any even other error. I agree its a client side error but i couldn't figure out what is exactly wrong.

Comment: Ah, if it's just a client side error, then the list of dependencies is unnecessary :) Now, please tell which  `Accept` request header was being sent and which response headers all were returned (particularly content type and length) and also if the response body actually contains something and if so what content exactly (raw XHTML source code or JSF-generated HTML output).

Comment: I have added the request and response headers

Comment: The response headers are incomplete and the response body is missing. But, you got a 500? Then an exception was been thrown in server side. Is this really not logged in server log? The "XML parsing error" still suggests that the client couldn't present the HTTP 500 error page.

Comment: I couldn't see any error message logged on the server. I have added  the full request headers which I got :)

Comment: Okay, you're seeing the error because the browser retrieved a response without `Content-Type` header and `Content-Length:0` while having `.xhtml` extension which will implicitly use a default content type of `application/xhtml+xml` which the browser then tries to parse, but couldn't because the body is entirely empty. However, that's not your main problem here. Your main problem is why it returned a HTTP 500 response without body. This indicates that an exception is thrown and that the server failed to return a proper error response. If there's really nothing logged then, well, run a debugger.